# NginxリバースプロキシでWordpress記事更新

Tags: wordpress, nginx

しても記事が反映されるのは普段使っているChromeだけで、IEや別のブラウザに表示させるにはNginxのキャッシュをすべて削除とNginx再起動の

```
rm -rf /var/cache/nginx/*
systemctl restart nginx
```

を行わないとだめですが、いい方法はないですか？
というかリバースプロキシを使うならこれが普通なんですかね？

Nginxの設定はこちらを参考にしました。

Nginxのリバースプロキシを使った設定
http://oxynotes.com/?p=8438#3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS上で動作するAMIMOTO AMIがNginxリバースプロキシを使用しているのですが、
そちらでは「Nginx Cache Controller」というプラグインを利用しています。
http://ja.amimoto-ami.com/2013/12/03/how-to-use-nginx-cache-controller/

質問者の環境でそのまま使えるかどうかはわかりませんが、
GitHubにソースコードもあるので参考にはなるのではないかと思います。